# Set constraints on view that is added to UIScrollView?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, constraints

I'm trying to programmatically add a view to a UIScrollView in such a way so that as I resize the subview, the UIScrollView contentSize will automatically match.

I've tried this:

```
private var _contentView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))

addSubview(_contentView)



let leading = NSLayoutConstraint(item: _contentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
let trailing = NSLayoutConstraint(item: _contentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
let top = NSLayoutConstraint(item: _contentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
let bottom = NSLayoutConstraint(item: _contentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

self.addConstraints([leading,trailing,top,bottom])
```

But I get an error at runtime about not being able to satisfy the constraints.

I've also tried setting constraints with the visual format and get a similar error:

```
let viewsDictionary = ["contentView":_contentView]

let hConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-0-[contentView]-0-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions.DirectionLeadingToTrailing, metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary)
let vConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-0-[contentView]-0-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions.DirectionLeadingToTrailing, metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary)

self.addConstraints(hConstraints)
self.addConstraints(vConstraints)
```

How can I properly add the constraints?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to NO/false on your content view.

In case of scroll views, the subviews need to have an intrinsic content size, or explicit width and height constraints to let the scroll view determine its content size.

So try adding width and height constraints to your content view.

Comment: That gets rid of the error, but it doesn't make the contentSize fit to the size of the subview.

Comment: I am setting the frame size of the subview and then calling needsUpdateConstraints() on each.

Comment: @AaronBratcher While using AutoLayout, think of frame as the output of the AL engine, rather than something you can set. So setting frame won't work as the AL system will over write that with the results of the constraints you've added.

Comment: My _contentView size is based on the subviews that will be dynamically added and removed as the user scrolls. I think I'll drop back to setting the contentSize manually and figuring out my other issue there.

Comment: @AaronBratcher so those subviews should have constraints in all dimensions that are able to resize contentView, which in turn would increase/decrease the scroll view's content size.